# CocoaPods with SVProgressHUD - SVIndefiniteAnimatedView not downloaded

Tags: ios, cocoapods, svprogresshud

I'm using **CocoaPods** and **SVProgressHUD** but from time to time after doing:

> pod install

All look good, but there are two files missing for SVProgressHUD:

```
SVIndefiniteAnimatedView.h
SVIndefiniteAnimatedView.m
```

I look on Pods/SVProgressHUD and I find all expected files except for the two above so the app doesn't compile.

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.10.0'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.13'
```

Any ideas what's going on?

In case if helps, if I add manually the two missing files to the folder everything works just fine.

Many thanks

Comment: just try performing pod update.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I got the latest already.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the most recent version of this library `1.1.3` hasn't been pushed to CocoaPods. The most recent one there is `1.1.2` (see [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/SVProgressHUD)). The tag for `1.1.3` which adds this file has already been created. You should ask nicely in a [new issue](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD/issues) and I'm sure someone will push the new podspec.

Comment: Do you mean that CocoaPods is trying to get v1.1.3 instead of v1.1.2 when I ask for pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1' - even though 1.1.3 is not live yet at the moment? Thanks for the advice, I will ask where you point me out.

Comment: I mean that you want 1.1.3 even though there isn't a podspec for it yet. You could tell CocoaPods to pull straight from master if you feel comfortable doing that. Otherwise someone needs to push a new podspec version.

Comment: Thank you Keith, but if you check my cocoapods, I'm just requesting 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1' so it shouldn't try to get 1.1.3 as it doesn't exist. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it can't download 1.1.3 because it doesn't exist. But 1.1.3 is the first version to have the classes you want.